# How to rename a primary key in Oracle such that it can be reused

Tags: oracle, ora-00955

On Oracle, I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Mig1"(
  "Id" INTEGER  NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT "PK_Mig1" PRIMARY KEY 
(
   "Id"  ) 
)
```

Then, I rename the PK:

```
ALTER TABLE "Mig1" RENAME CONSTRAINT "PK_Mig1" TO "PK_XXX"
```

Then, I rename the table:

```
ALTER TABLE "Mig1" RENAME TO "XXX"
```

Then, I try to create another table that uses the name of the previously renamed table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Mig1"(
  "Id" INTEGER  NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT "PK_Mig1" PRIMARY KEY 
(
   "Id"  ) 
)
```

At this point I get: `An error occurred: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`. And this is because somehow the primary key of the first table is still around in some way although it was renamed. If I try to create the second table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Mig1"(
  "Id" INTEGER  NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT "YYY" PRIMARY KEY 
(
   "Id"  ) 
)
```

it works. So how do I rename the primary key correctly with all of its associated resources such that its name can be reused?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an index associated with the primary key constraint, and it is probably still called "PK_Mig1".  Try this:

```
ALTER INDEX "PK_Mig1" RENAME TO "PK_XXX";
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Sorry, did not know that Oracle is maintaining an extra index besides the constraint (coming from the SQL Server world).

Comment: Oracle creates (or hijacks) an index in all cases to maintain primary key and unique constraints.  Otherwise, how else could you do it?