# Oracle SQL: renaming primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

How do I rename a primary key so that it is also renamed in another table as a foreign key?

Comment: In Oracle can we have same object name for two different objects ?

Comment: Look at this question [How to rename a primary key in Oracle such that it can be reused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252355/how-to-rename-a-primary-key-in-oracle-such-that-it-can-be-reused)